# How do I check for minimum permissions and allow all parent roles permission in a DRY way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, rolify

Say I have 4 roles: `user`, `agent`, `admin`, `superadmin`.

Where each role has subsequently more permissions on all objects in my app.

I am using Rolify, CanCan & Devise.

What I would like to do is, whenever I want to enable something - say:

```
<%= link_to "Create New User", new_user_registration_path if current_user.has_role? :superadmin %>
```

I would like for that link to show if the person is either an `admin` or a `superadmin`. I know I could simply just do an `||` - but that doesn't seem very DRY, especially since I will have to do `current_user.has_role? :superadmin || current_user.has_role? :admin`.

Imagine there are some links/assets that I want `agent, admin & superadmin` to have access to.

How do I do this in a DRY way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do u check roles instead of checking a permissions? As I know cancan support `can?` and `cannot?` methods which can help in your situation. You should write something like this

```rails
<%= link_to "Create New User", new_user_registration_path if can?(:create, User) %>
```

[Usefull link about this feature](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Checking-Abilities)